# Destroy and Respawn a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am creating a sort of game where you have to sell some food. I am programming the prototype of the game, and my idea is that after you place the food (in this case an hamburger) on a certain place, it's sold. I would like that this gameObject disappear and respawn in another point, but my script doesnt work at all. Can you help me? Thanks a lot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class sellingSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject food;
    public bool foodExist;

    void Start()
    {
        food = Resources.Load("food") as GameObject;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        food = GameObject.Find("food");
        if(GameObject.Find("food") != null)
        {
            foodExist = true;
        }
        if (foodExist == false)
        {
            Instantiate(food, new Vector3(2.996f, 1.249f, -7.474f), Quaternion.identity);
            foodExist = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "food")
        {
            Destroy(food);
            foodExist = false;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a prefab, you then instantiate the prefab  keep a reference and then destroy that reference. You can’t spawn something you’ve destroyed. Just like you can’t photocopy paper you burnt.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you instantiating the food obj with Resources.Load and then in the update using GameObject.Find?

```
Instantiate(food, new Vector3(2.996f, 1.249f, -7.474f), Quaternion.identity);
```

Also in the above line you are trying to instantiate an object that is null, if there isn't a food object you cannot make a "clone" of it.

May I suggest a different approach? Instead of destroying the object use the SetActive() method and then re-locate the object to the desired position.

Comment: Thank you really much. It's my first times handling with Unity, so i'm trying to learn. I'll try a different approach just like you suggest :)

Comment: Don't worry everything will feel fine tuned with time :) Comment here if you need more help or find yourself stuck again, don't be afraid to ask questions.